# Writing to a Text file on a server from Unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

Hi I have been making an app in Unity and I have been trying to add code that will log User actions i.e. they have made a certain game object appear. What I am trying to do is write to a .txt file stored on a server I have the following code which is based on:

```
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/984290/upload-txt-file-to-server-using-php.html
```

and they suggest it works, for me it is not writing anything to the file.

Here is my PHP code (SaveData.php):

```
<?php
         $Action = $_GET["action"];
         $Date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

         $myFile = "TestingData.txt";
         $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
         fwrite($fh,$Action . "," . $Date . "\n");
         fclose($fh);
 ?>
```

And here is the C# (SaveData.cs) I am attaching to the game objects I change the Action value in the inspector window:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SaveData : MonoBehaviour {

public string postDataURL = "http://arinstructionman.byethost7.com/SaveData.php?"; //add a ? to your url

         public string Action;

     void Start()
     {

         StartCoroutine(PostData(Action));
     }

     IEnumerator PostData(string action)
     {

         string post_url = postDataURL + "action=" + WWW.EscapeURL(action);

         WWW data_post = new WWW(post_url);

         yield return data_post;

         if (data_post.error != null)
         {
             print("There was an error saving data: " + data_post.error);
         }
     } 
 }
```

If I copy the post_url value and run it in the browser it seems to work fine, can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

post_url output:

```
http://arinstructionman.byethost7.com/SaveData.php?action=Plane+Visible
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error as such its just that no content is being added to the file

Comment: Can you Debug.Log the post_url variable for us to look at?

Comment: @Robert I've added the output above

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I don't see anything wrong with that...
You could try putting an echo at the bottom of the php, and reading the text back in Unity (data_post.text), just to make sure that the script is executing correctly from WWW. Basically trying to narrow down when side is breaking down.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look at that

Comment: @randomer check if you have permission to write on the file

Comment: @Jansen I changed the permissions on both the PHP and the txt file to 777 at the start just to check that it didn't seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying this with `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` and see if you get a different response.
Also, you can use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to open, write, and close the file all in one line, and using the `FILE_APPEND` flag to prevent overwriting the existing file. If the file does not exist, this will also create the file for you.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST["action"])) 
    {
        echo ("NO DATA RECIEVED");
        return;
    }

    $action = $_POST["action"];
    $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
    $data = "{$action},{$date}\n";
    $myFile = "TestingData.txt";

    if(file_put_contents($myFile, $data, FILE_APPEND))
        echo ("success");
    else
        echo ("failed to write file);
 ?>
```

And use [`WWWform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) to `POST` data to the PHP file:

```
public string postDataURL = "http://arinstructionman.byethost7.com/SaveData.php";
public string Action = "some action";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PostData(Action));
}

IEnumerator PostData(string action)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("action", action);
    WWW dataPost = new WWW(postDataURL, form);

    yield return dataPost;

    if (dataPost.error != null)
        print("There was an error saving data: " + data_post.error);
    else
        print(dataPost.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

)

Just in case someone is trying to implement that and it doesn't work like it was the case for me.
I found a fix, for sure is not the best implementation, but at least it works for the moment :

If your server doesn't use **PHP5** you will have to use **PHP4** function

(coming from : http://memo-web.fr/categorie-php-126/ ):

```
function file_put_contents_PHP4($myFile, $data) {
        $f = @fopen($myFile, 'w');
        if (!$f) {
            echo ("failed to write file");
            return false;
        } else {
            $resultat= fwrite($f, $data);
            fclose($f);
            echo ("success");
            return $resultat;
        }
    }
```

For sure we could test if PHP5 is available with something like, but my php knowledge is kind of bad ahah :

```
 if (!function_exists('file_put_contents')) 
{
  function file_put_contents_PHP4...
{
```

**The Scripts :**

**SaveData.php**, in your server online:

```
<?php
$action = $_POST["action"];
$data = "{$action}";
$myFile = "TestingData.txt";


    if($action == "") 
    {
        echo ("NO DATA RECIEVED");
        return;
    }
    else
        file_put_contents_PHP4($myFile, $data);


    function file_put_contents_PHP4($myFile, $data) {
        $f = @fopen($myFile, 'w');
        if (!$f) {
            echo ("failed to write file");
            return false;
        } else {
            $resultat= fwrite($f, $data);
            fclose($f);
            echo ("success");
            return $resultat;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Unity c# Script** :

```
[SerializeField] private string postDataURL = "http://yourebsite.com/SaveData.php";
[SerializeField] private string Action = "some action";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PostData(Action));
}

IEnumerator PostData(string action)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("action", action);
    WWW dataPost = new WWW(postDataURL, form);

    yield return dataPost;

    if (dataPost.error != null)
        print("There was an error saving data: " + dataPost.error);
    else
        print(dataPost.text);
}
```

Don't forget to put an empty text file "TestingData.txt" next to "SaveData.php" into the server.
Don't forget as well to add the correct adress to SaveData.php in the Inspector.
I uploaded them to an old personal server using Filezilla and everything is working as intended.

Cheers :-)